# Generating Ed25519 key/pair with LibreSSL on mac: missing algorithm

Tags: macos, openssl, jwt

I am trying to generate a Ed25519 key/pair using

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm Ed25519 -out ed25519key.pem
```

However, on my MacOS I get this:

```
Algorithm Ed25519 not found
```

I am running OpenSSL / LibreSSL 3.2.5 but I have no idea why this algorithm wouldn't be available.

Is there something I'm missing / need to install?

Comment: is the name case sensitive?

Comment: possibly, but in my command I am using "Ed25519" same as in the error.

Comment: The error just spits out whatever you put in

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the default OpenSSL (LibreSSL) that comes with MacOS (even in MacOS 11.2.3) simply doesn't have the algorithm.

I installed OpenSSL 1.1.1k via brew separately (in `/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1` ) and using that binary the command works.

Comment: This worked. After installing OpenSSL using "brew" don't forget to add "/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin" to your PATH.